# generating 2^24 tables which differ only at one bit with c#

Tags: c#, binary, cryptanalysis

These days, I am working in the field of **cryptanalysis** and have started to do programming with C#

Now,
For finding the 5 optimal s-boxes(i mean those 2^24 tables), they should be generated, first.**I know everything about the criteria for finding the optimal ones.**

Here, a **sbox** is 2*8 table which the first row include the numbers between 0-7(binary:000 - 111)(**as sbox input**) and in the second row, every input(0 - 7) is associated with a number,as below:

The first sbox:

```
input     000   001 010 011 100 101 110 111  
output    000   000 000 000 000 000 000 000
```

The second sbox which differs only at one bit:

```
input   000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111  
output  001 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
```

The Third one which differs only at one bit coparing to the second one:

```
input   000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111  
output  010 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
```

and the 2^24-th one:

```
input   000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111  
output  111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111
```

Question is how to generate these tables? i don't know how to put **for loop** or save the results in array separately for each sbox.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < Math.Pow(2, 24); j++)
  {
           Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(j, 2).PadRight(24, '0'));
  }
```

Comment: we can use 16777216 instead of Math.Pow(2,24)

Comment: that's not important. all permutations should be generated.

Answer (score 0):

May be these lines of code will help you:

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
      Dictionary< long, Tuple <input, output> > dict = new Dictionary<long,Tuple<input,output>> () ;
      for (long i = 0 ;  i < (long) (2^28) ;  i++) {
        input ip = new input( );
        output op = new output( );
        for( int j = 0; j < 8; j++ ) {
          //you have to write your own lodic for creating input and output
          unit isp = new unit( );
          unit osp = new unit( );
          ip.iData[ j ] = isp;
          op.oData[ j ] = osp;
        }
        dict.Add( i, Tuple.Create( ip, op ) );
      }    
    }
  }

  public class input {
    public  unit [] iData = new unit [8] ; 
  }

  public class output {
    public unit[ ] oData = new unit[ 8 ];
  }

  public class unit {
    public int item1;
    public int item2;
    public int item3;
  }
```

However this problem can be addressed in many ways.

Comment: thanks. input is fixed, numbers between 0-7. the problem is exactly "how to generate outputs" ? How to change the one bit? how to move forward? THANK YOU,AGAIN.

Comment: I thought, you know how to generate the data and you have problem related to looping. I will try if I could help you.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand you fully. If you will find out solution please post it here. It would be interesting to see...

Comment: let me explain. there are 2^24 tables which in all of them, **the input row is fixed**. only **output** changes and in just one bit comparing to the previous one. i don't know how to do that.

Comment: for example, table 1 and 2 above are different at just one bit of output